# Change Add To Cart To Buy Now drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

Hello currently I am making a online e store using drupal Commerce so i want to change add to cart button to Buy Now So Ho Can I able To Do Help It Out

Answer (score 2):

If you want to alter the text for a particular form you can alter it using `hook_form_alter`

Get the ID of the form for the product display where you are trying to change the text & do something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){//replace your module name with MYMODULE
  if(strpos($form_id, 'commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-65') !== false){//my form ID is "commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-65", replace it with your form ID.
    $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Buy Now');//Put the text which you want to make appear instead of "Add to cart".
  }
}
```

You could also use [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) Module to achieve the same.